# Как при выборе select и при введении текста в input, все тексты вставить через запятую в другой input

Tags: html, input, autocomplete, html-select, ctags

Есть `HTML` выбора параметров автомобилей

```html
<select id="car_year" class="year" name="q[year]">
  <option value="0">Год выпуска</option>
  <option value="1890">1890</option>
  <option value="1891">1891</option>
  <option value="1892">1892</option>
  <option value="1893">1893</option>
  <option value="1894">1894</option>
  <option value="1895">1895</option>
</select>


<input style="width: 80%;" onfocus="this.value='';" placeholder="Пробег км" value="Пробег км" type="text" id="bdF16" class="manFlOth4" size="7" name="other4" maxlength="7">

<input style="width: 60%;" onfocus="this.value='';" placeholder="Цена" value="Цена" class="manFlOth2" maxlength="13" type="text" id="bdF14" name="other2" title="Qiymət AZN">
```

И есть input, в который надо вручную выводить теги **метки** через запятую

```html
<input type="text" name="tags" id="suggEdit" style="width: 100%; font-size: 11px; position: relative;" maxlength="150" class="x-selectable u-suggedit undefined" autocomplete="off">
```

А мне надо сделать так, что бы при выборе из select option допустим **1890**
авто вставился в input **метки** через запятую.
Потом далее при выводе **ПРОБЕГ КМ** допустим 65000 и **ЦЕНА** допустим 10000 тоже вставился в **INPUT МЕТКИ** через запятую. В итоге должно получится вот так 1890,65000,10000

Answer (score 1):

Этот скрипт соберёт в теги все значения из селектов и инпутов, у которых есть класс add-to-tags

```js
var fields = $('#auto-info').find('input.add-to-tags, select.add-to-tags');
fields.on('change keyup', function(){
 var tags = [];
 fields.each(function(){
  if ($(this).val().length)
  {
   tags.push($(this).val());
  }
 });
 $('input[name=tags]', '#auto-info').val(tags.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="auto-info">
 <select class="year add-to-tags" name="q[year]">
  <option value="0">Год выпуска</option>
  <option value="1890">1890</option>
  <option value="1891">1891</option>
  <option value="1892">1892</option>
  <option value="1893">1893</option>
  <option value="1894">1894</option>
  <option value="1895">1895</option>
 </select>

 <input class="add-to-tags" placeholder="Пробег км" type="text" name="other4" />
 <input class="add-to-tags" placeholder="Цена" type="text" name="other2" />
 <input placeholder="Теги" type="text" name="tags" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/sbkm73on/5/

```js
$('#car_year, #bdF16, #bdF14').on('input', function() {
  var year = $('#car_year option:selected').val();
  var mileage = $('#bdF16').val();
  var price = $('#bdF14').val();

  $('#suggEdit').val(year+','+mileage+','+price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="car_year" class="year" name="q[year]">
  <option value="0">Год выпуска</option>
  <option value="1890">1890</option>
  <option value="1891">1891</option>
  <option value="1892">1892</option>
  <option value="1893">1893</option>
  <option value="1894">1894</option>
  <option value="1895">1895</option>
</select>


<input style="width: 80%;" placeholder="Пробег км" type="text" id="bdF16" class="manFlOth4" size="7" name="other4" maxlength="7">

<input style="width: 60%;" placeholder="Цена" class="manFlOth2" maxlength="13" type="text" id="bdF14" name="other2" title="Qiymət AZN">

<input type="text" name="tags" id="suggEdit" style="width: 100%; font-size: 11px; position: relative;" maxlength="150" class="x-selectable u-suggedit undefined" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответь. до того вы ответили, я нашел другой вариант скрипта, но не ваш, не мой скрипт не корректно работает на моем сайте, проблем такая,! тот который ваш скрипт, в этом  [ссылке](https://jsfiddle.net/sbkm73on/5/) работает как надо, и мой скрипт тоже самое, но оба скрипты на моем сайте работает, что возникает, если мне надо выбрать  **Год выпуска** не выводится в input-е если выбрать первую и вторую функции тогда выводится все подряд, просто я тут прибавил еще две функции **select** вот ссылка на [ту страницу](http://avtousta.ucoz.com/board/) тот поиск написано AXTAR